# WordPress - "Pages and posts have a different sidebar" in place of the actual sidebar on a page

Tags: wordpress

This embarrassing text shows on my page in place of a sidebar. I have searched all around the dashboard to find where I can edit this text/add a real sidebar etc. I added a "Pages" widget to the Page Sidebar widget in the Widgets menu, but this had no effect on the presentation of the sidebar.

Where can I add a sidebar to my page or at least hide this text?

Comment: Maybe it's embedded in the theme. Try switching themes, see if the text is still there.

Comment: what theme are you using? does it supports a sidebar? we need more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, changing the permalink of the page from `about` to `about-me` fixed the problem, and the correct sidebar shows now.